# How to put dynamic form to fieldset in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I need to put a `form` inside `fieldset` dynamically. This is what i did.This is jquery,

```js
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#mainPage", function () {
                if (sessionStorage.login_state != 1) {
                    alert('You don\'t have permition to login here !');
                    window.location.href = 'index.html';
                } else {
                    var name = sessionStorage.name;
                    var email = sessionStorage.email;
                    var dit = sessionStorage.dit;
                    $('#userinfo-form').append("<form method='POST' action='index.html'>" +
                            "<lable for='i_name'>Name : </label>" +
                            "<input class=\"ui-disabled\" type='text' id='i_name' name='i_name' value='" + name + "' data-mini='true' />" +
                            "<lable for='i_email'>Email : </label>" +
                            "<input class=\"ui-disabled\" type='text' id='i_email' name='i_email' value='" + email + "' data-mini='true' />" +
                            "<lable for='i_dit'>DIT : </label>" +
                            "<input class=\"ui-disabled\" type=\"text\" id=\"i_dit\" name='i_dit' value='" + dit + "' data-mini='true' />" +
                            "<lable for='i_newPassword'>New Password : </label>" +
                            "<input class=\"ui-disabled\" type='password' id='i_newPassword' name='i_newPassword' value='' data-mini='true' />" +
                            "<a id=\"user_edit\" class=\"ui-btn-c ui-mini ui-btn btn-primary ui-icon-mail ui-shadow\" >Edit</a>" +
                            "<a id=\"user_update\" class=\"show-page-loading-msg ui-btn btn-primary ui-shadow ui-hide\" data-textonly=\"false\" data-btntype=\"updateinfo\" data-textvisible=\"true\" data-msgtext=\"Please waite ...\" type=\"button\"  data-theme=\"c\">Update Info</a>"+
                            "</form>").enhanceWithin();
                }
            });
```

this is html,

```html
<div data-role="panel" id="p_userinfo" data-position="right" data-theme="c" data-swipe-close="true" >
                <!--<a id="logout" class="ui-btn-c ui-btn ui-shadow ui-mini" >Logout</a>-->
                <h2>User Info</h2>
                <div class="ui-field-contain" id="userinfo_field">
                    <fieldset id="userinfo-form" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
```

But this code not working. doest not show anything on page. But if i chage the css as `display:block` for the `form` from the browser `form` will display.

Comment: use display:block than

Comment: @madalinivascu is that the answer ? i need to know how it is happening.

Comment: your form has the default display:inline and doesn't show up the markup is there but the form is hidden in the page view

Comment: you simply add in the apend string to the form tag : `style="display:block;"`

Answer (score 0):

If you've got all your HTML body code inside a `<div data-role="page">` (as per the jQM docs @ https://api.jquerymobile.com/page/) just run `(".ui-page").trigger("create")` on it, after you've placed the HTML in the DOM.
Let me know if you need further info :)

Comment: hey thanks... i did this. But form not shows.. only way after add the form just add `display:block` for the form. am i right